# how do i use jQuery get the parent radcombobox control object from the checkbox click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a radcombobox with checkboxes turned on. I wrote a jQuery script to add a click event to all of them. What I need to move on to the next step is a way to get the combobox in which that item/checkbox resides. Something like this:

```
$(."comboBoxTag.find(":checkbox").click(
        function(){
            var cboObject = $(this).???
        });
```

this way I can do things like access the telerik api methods like cboObject.get_items();

I have the control tagged with a CSS class called "AssigneeTag", but doing a .closest(".AssigneeTag") isn't returning anything...

any ideas?

UPDATE:
As requested:

```
<h1>Tickets Assigned to Me</h1>
    <rad:RadListView runat="server" ID="lsvTickets">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="divContainer" class="divContainer">
                <div id="divTicketHeader" class="divTicketHeader">
                    <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblTicketHead" Width="100%" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="5" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <asp:TableRow HorizontalAlign="Left">
                            <asp:TableCell  Width="25%">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Subject") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
                            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell Width="25%">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Status.Key") %>' />
                            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell Width="25%">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblReportedBy" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CreatedBy.Key") %>' />
                            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell Width="25%">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDateOpened" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DateOpened") %>' />
                            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table></div><div id="divTicketBody" class="divComments">
                        <rad:RadListView runat="server" ID="lsvActions" DataSource='<%#Eval("Comments") %>' ItemPlaceholderID="ph1" ClientIDMode="Static">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div id="divComment" class="divComment">
                                    <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblComment" CellPadding="5">
                                        <asp:TableRow>
                                            <asp:TableCell Width="15%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                <rad:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="imgCommenter" Width="50" Height="50" /><br />
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="[action author]" /><br />
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CreateDate", "{0:MMM d, yyy hh:mm}") %>'
                                                     CssClass="commenterText"/><br />
                                            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CommentText") %>' />
                                            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table></div></ItemTemplate><LayoutTemplate>
                                <center>                            
                                <div id="divAddComment" style="width: 500px;" class="CommentTopLevel">
                                    <div id="divCommentControls" style="margin: 8px 0px 8px 0px;">
                                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfID" Value='<%#Eval("TicketID") %>' />
                                        <rad:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cboStatus" DataSource='<%#GetStatuses() %>' DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="Support_StatusID" CssClass="StatusTag" EnableViewState="true" />
                                        <rad:RadCombobox runat="server" ID="cboAssignTo" DataSource='<%#GetAssignees() %>' DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Guid" ItemDataBound="Assignees_Bound" CssClass="AssigneeTag" CheckBoxes="true" OnItemChecked="AssigneeChecked" />
                                        <rad:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="txtComment" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500" Height="100" CssClass="CommentBox" /><br />
                                    </div>

                                    <div style="height: 35px;">
                                        <div style="float:right; margin: 3px 0 0 0; ">
                                            <rad:RadButton runat="server" CssClass="submitTag" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" /><br />
                                            <div class="SubmitStatus"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </center>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server" />
                            </LayoutTemplate>
                        </rad:RadListView>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </rad:RadListView>
```

This is a listview with another listview nested in the itemtemplate. in the itemtemplate of the inner list resides the controls. The combobox im referring to is named cboAssignTo. It is a Telerik combobox, so it does not work like a traditionial DropDown menu, which I think is what is really complicating this on top of the fact that the comboboxes are dynamically generated. I was able to do things like $(this).closest(".rcbTag") to get the values of the other combobox called cboStatus, but this other combobox involves a bit more as it has checkboxes.

EDIT:

Here is a watered down easier to read version of what stage I'm at. This is the HTML generated by a single instance of this combobox:

```
<div id="lsvTest" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Default RcbTag" style="width:160px;">
    <table summary="combobox" style="border-width:0;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:100%">
        <tr class="rcbReadOnly">
            <td style="margin-top:-1px;margin-bottom:-1px;width:100%;" class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft">
                <input name="lsvTest" type="text" class="rcbInput" id="lsvTest_Input" value="" style="display: block;" readonly="readonly" />
            </td>
            <td style="margin-top:-1px;margin-bottom:-1px;" class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight">
                <a id="lsvTest_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- 2012.1.215.40 -->
    <div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index:6000;">
        <div id="lsvTest_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Default " style="float:left;display:none;">
            <div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="width:100%;">
                <ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
                    <li class="rcbItem "><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox" />One</li>
                    <li class="rcbItem "><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox" />Two</li>
                    <li class="rcbItem "><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox" />Three</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="lsvTest_ClientState" name="lsvTest_ClientState" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

Just looking at this, I feel like clicking a checkbox and then using $(this).closest(".RcbTag") should traverse all the way to the top and grab the outer div, but it is not.

Comment: Can you please create a js fiddle please with the html structure included, so that we actually know what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the other question, I think your life will be easier if you stick with the Telerik-sanctioned methods.  Here is how you could do it using them:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientItemChecked(sender, eventArgs) {
        var item = eventArgs.get_item();
        var combo = item.get_comboBox(); // Now you have a reference to the parent ComboBox
    }
</script>
```

And the RadComboBox itself:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" 
    OnClientItemChecked="OnClientItemChecked" CheckBoxes="true">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issues using [jQuery parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) calls, did you try this?

Comment: i did try this to several different levels, and I was able to get objects, but I dont think they were the correct objects because i was not able to call any known methods

Comment: and the reason i dont really want to go that route is that if i do anything to change the hierarchy, it will break.